# How to Connect Modems to Wall?

Tags: walls, connectors

I see this kind of connectors at the bottom of each my modem but I cannot use them for anything because the package is not provided with particular screws and I cannot find those screws anywhere etc AliExpress by searching `modem connector wall` and the biggest electronic store in Finland, [Verkkokauppa.com](https://www.verkkokauppa.com/fi/search?q=ruuvi) with *ruuvi* (=screw) -search where the customer service also says and confirms (19/8-2016) that they do not have any screws suitable for the attachment. It would be great to find specific names for such screws.

Screws are from the standard Ikea's screw package in the figures. 
Fig. 1 connectors are the right-hand-side, Fig. 2 Screw unstably in the key slot, Fig. 3 Two bigger screws there which cannot completely fit the plastic but may be sufficient

[image]
[image]
[image]

You can put two screws in the keyhole slot but I cannot find anything that just fits there so the screws are in little angle and unstably there in Fig. 2. I think big screws are not the right ones for the task. Perphaps, something specific could be found.

Factors

- length of screws
- size of necks in the screws

Modem/router in the picture: TP-Link Archer MR-200

Comment: Modems often come with a couple of screws and plastic wall plugs. It may be worth looking in the modem's packaging, if you still have it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, I have it. Bought yesterday. It does not have them. - - I have never hand modems which would have had such screws in the package itself.

Comment: If it had had them, there would have been two [pan head screws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw#Screw_head_shapes) and two [wall plugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_plug). They would not be large as there is not much weight to support. [Double-sided foam tape](https://www.amazon.com/3M-Scotch-Mounting-5-Inch-75-Inch/dp/B00004Z498) can be a nuisance to remove, although you don't end up with two holes in the wall to fill if you ever remove the modem.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It would be great if you could say which *pan head screws*. There are much of them here http://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?initiative_id=SB_20160819031831&site=glo&g=y&SearchText=pan+head+screws&page=2

Comment: I think you are very much **overcomplicating** this. Any screw will do the job as long as it fits into the slot and stays there, which the screws in your images do just fine. It's unclear to me why and what kind of perfect fit you are expecting from the slot-screwhead connection. The "little angle" doesn't matter at all. Apply a minimum of common sense: these screws are there to hold the modem to the wall, nothing less, but most importantly: nothing more. Seriously, just put 2 screws into the wall at the right distance and depth and be done with it. This shouldn't take longer than 10 minutes.

Comment: @ducttape True! Case is only about correct screws.

Comment: I mount such things with flathead screws, usually. Only tricky parts are getting the distance between screws exactly right (making a paper pattern with a pencil while holding the paper on the device is very useful there), and getting the amount that the screw sticks out from the wall exactly right for a snug fit without being too tight.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This really shouldn't be an answer since [Chris H.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/97664/34147)'s answer nailed it (and should be accepted), but I want to address several comments from several answers, and this is far too long for a comment on any of them.

1. Since your modem doesn't seem to have come with screws and drywall anchors, you'll have to find something

   1. You are now looking for hardware, not electronics, so do **not** go to the electronics store to find a screw, go to a hardware store. Also, don't bother with trying to order them online. You only need 2 and the few cents, fractions of a Euro (sorry, don't know the correct term), whatever, that you save will not make up for the time you wait for them to be shipped or the annoyance of discovering that they don't fit well.
   2. It seems you're in Finland. I've never been there (would love to visit some day!) so I don't know what you have in the way of hardware stores, but here in the US, we have massive hardware stores with aisles full of screws of varying types. I would suggest you take the modem (without its box) to the store (stop at the front desk if necessary to show them you're bringing it in with you, though they probably don't sell modems at the hardware store & won't question you when you walk out without paying for it) then wander down the screw aisle trying different screws until I found one who's head fits nicely into the hole in the back of the modem and who's shank will slide into the slot, then buy a small package (or just 2 if you can get them individually).
   3. *Side note*: having a few extra screws from this project is a nice start to the collection of random screws that you'll need to make it through life - these types of little projects crop up all the time and a jar of screws to sort through to find something that's close enough to get the next random small job done is very satisfying!
   4. The screw heads don't have to be a precise fit. Actually if they're *too* snug, they'll make installing the modem on the wall very difficult. You want a bit of play around the screw head so you can easily slide the modem on once the screws are on the wall.
   5. The screws you show in your picture look like they'll work just fine, especially if you install them into a stud behind your drywall. (See 2.2, below).
   6. Pan-head screws would be ideal, with their relatively thin head and flat bottom, however a wood screw (with a sloped bottom) will work just fine. I'm more likely to end up with a wood screw (from my random collection of extra screws from previous projects) for this type of hanging assignment than a pan-head, and I've never had anything fall off a wall. Actually, as light as the modem is, pretty much *any* screw will work if the head & shank fit the slot you've got.
   7. The one screw you do *not* want is a machine screw with a flat bottom. These are designed to go into pre-tapped threads and will not cut their own threads very well into drywall, studs, or the side of your desk.
   8. If you're installing onto the side of your desk, you'll want much, much shorter screws with threads all the way to the bottom of the head, since your desk panel is much thinner. (Those pictured will stick all the way through the side of the desk and snag your leg. Every. Single. Time. Guaranteed!)
2. If you're installing this onto drywall, you'll want to either:

   1. Drywall anchors which will allow you to put the modem anywhere you want. These usually come with screws sized to fit the anchors. Or,
   2. Get some longer screws (1.5-2", approx 35-50mm) and make sure they go into a stud behind the drywall.
3. Once you've got your screws:

   1. Use one of the many, all valid methods mentioned in the comments on Chris H's answer to locate the screws on the wall.
   2. Pre-drill holes if you're going into the side of your desk or into a stud or using a wall anchor.
   3. If you're not using a wall anchor in drywall, you'll *probably* be fine. The modem itself weighs next to nothing and won't put a huge strain on the drywall. The biggest issue will be the additional weight of the cables (power & network) hanging out of it (mitigate this by hanging it lower to the ground, though, if it's also a router, that could impact your WiFi range), and you wiggling it around (it'll happen) as you insert cables.
   4. Insert your screws into the wall leaving 1/4 - 3/8" (6-10mm) of <s>thread</s> screw exposed.
4. Now the fun starts!

   1. You'll have to fiddle around a little bit to align the heads of both screws with the hanger holes *at the same time*, then slide the modem down (gravity is your friend!) so the screws move into the slot part of the hanger.
   2. If the modem is *pretty* snug to wall and doesn't wobble *too* much (how much? Don't know, it's your modem you get to decide when it's secure enough), you're done. Plug in your cables, grab a drink and dive into your favorite game/movie/whatever.
   3. If the screw heads won't get into their slots at the back of the modem at all, grab your screwdriver, back the screws out a turn (or so), go back to step 4.1, then repeat until you meet the criteria in step 4.2.
   4. If the screw heads go into the slots, but the modem wobbles excessively, the feet are nowhere near the wall, and all-in-all, you have the distinct feeling that it will fall off if someone in London sips his tea without his pinky raised, then unhook it, grab the screwdriver, turn the screws in a bit, then return to step 4.1.
   5. Repeat the steps above until you're successfully at 4.2. Note that you do *not* have to have a precise, exact fit of the feet against the wall for this to be securely attached. As a matter of fact, you'll want a couple of mm of play to make it easier it install (and remove at some point in the future, modems do die). I've used hanger systems like this for anything from a power strip to the leg of a desk to a *large* nick-knack shelf on the wall with tons of my wife's display items. None of them are super snug, nor are they excessively wobbly and none has ever made good an unplanned escape. *Close enough* is your guiding principle here.

If things go well for you, you'll do step 4.1 and everything will be perfect. Odds are, you'll be like me and you'll alternate between 4.2 & 4.3 a couple of times until you get it just right. That's just the way this game works.

Answer (score 25):

That's a keyhole slot for a screw. It's not specific to a modem (though I'll keep using the word here). In this case it's actually a double keyhole. The idea is that you put a screw into the wall with a head that just goes through the central circle, then slide the modem so that the screw head is trapped in the slot.

Normally you'd have at least two and the distance between them has to be spot on. Also they're normally set up so that you slide the modem downwards onto the screws. You also have to screw the screw in the right amount so it's secure and doesn't wobble.

Finding the right screw can be a little tricky especially if you have hollow walls that need some sort of anchor. But any hardware store should have something.

Comment: You can find out where to drill the holes by making a cardboard or paper template of the hole placement. The easiest way to do it would be to put a piece of paper flat on the back of it and shine a light at it to see where the holes are, and then mark them. After that, you can put the piece of paper on the wall and transfer the marks. If you are looking for something more sturdy than attaching into drywall, you can get a piece of plywood and mount it to that instead.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson good point.  I've put things on photocopiers to make templates in the past - but that worked better when hardware was beige.

Comment: For lining up 2 keyholes I wouldn't make a template.   Pencil a straight line on the wall using a level.  Measure the keyholes center to center.  Install 2 screws on the line that same distance apart.

Comment: @Tyson that's another way to do it.  I've had odd cases where there is a vertical and horizontal separation; then a template is nice even with only 2 holes.

Comment: you can use @JasonHutchinson suggestion, but without the light. Simply lightly rub the side of the lead of your pencil in the area where they keyholes are. You'll get a light shading everywhere, but the pencil will 'catch' on the edges and leave a nice line where you need to place your holes. Your case, with its aggressive pattern on the back will leave an interesting pattern on your paper (only shade where the holes are, not the whole paper), but you'll quickly figure out where they go. Just be sure to hold the paper securely in place while doing it - if it moves, your holes will be off.

Comment: @FreeMan: I have used masking tape before. Learned the technique in Popular Mechanics. No residue is left on the wall. Put the tape on the bottom of the device, use a pencil to poke a hole. Then put the tape on the wall and use a level to ensure it is straight. Then drill through the drywall, use a good anchor and go from there.

Comment: What ideally you'd use a pan head or button head, but for drywall fixings you may have to use whatever fits or comes with them. The diameter is more important than any picture and you need to check that yourself as you have the modem.

Comment: Sometimes there are two orthogonal slots to each hole allowing to move the modem into two different final positions. If possible, pick the one that's orthogonal to the direction of network cable slots. This way, inserting and removing those cables will not move the modem in the direction of the slot which might cause it to come loose. Not a big deal if you only use wifi.

Comment: Whatever screw you choose, try it out in the slot before you install the screw in the wall.  Some heads will be too thick/thin/small/large/etc.  -- Voice of Experience, out.

Comment: Please, see the body. How can you put a screw or two screws stably to the keyhole slot? I could not find any screw in the standard Ikea screw package that fits the hole, stably in the end.

Comment: Ikea is a furniture shop. I said hardware store. The ikea screw packs are useful for fixing *their* products to *some* walls. Without accurate measurements of the diameter of the circular part of the hole, the width of the slot and the depth of the hole (which you probably don't have the tool to measure), we can't recommend anything specific. Even then the type of wall is important. That's why I say you should take it to a hardware shop. It's one screw per hole. I've tried to find you a diagram online but it appears to be regarded as too common to be worth it.

Comment: Sorry, @ChrisH, I didn't mean to steal your thunder and check mark. I did give you a +1 before I commented on your answer, and well before I wrote up mine.

Comment: @Freeman, you've gone into much more detail even taking into account my comments - you deserve it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a drywall anchor (the plastic hole insert you mentioned) with a *machine screw* of matching diameter. The screws can’t be too long or it won’t fit in the wall, but some plastic anchors let the screw be longer than the plastic.

You can probably find little kits at a hardware store that includes screws and anchors, made for attaching things to the wall so the length will be good.  Just make sure the screw head fits in the keyhole slot.

Another answer and comments suggests how to measure the hole positions.  Just be sure to drill the correct size for the anchors, or they’ll fall out.

An alternative I’ve used for a few things is **foam core mounting tape**.

Comment: Generally, a standard wood or drywall screw is used with a drywall anchor, not a machine screw. Machine screws have a flat end and usually a much finer thread pitch and are designed to go into pre-tapped threads (usually in a fairly solid material like plastic or metal), while wood/drywall screws have a sharp, pointed end (for making their own hole), and coarser pitched threads for holding the screw in a softer material. Also, if you pick up a package of drywall anchors, they'll _usually_ come with appropriately sized screws (for the anchors, not for the mounting slots in the modem).